# how to change the background color of a row using javascript when the user enters a text in a textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to have an ontextchanged function so basically when the user enters something   in txtpart, I want to be able to check in teh gridview and see if that part exists in the gridview. if it does i want to change the background color of that row to green..

How can I do this using javascript ?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOrderItems" runat="server" GridLines="None" Visible="true" CssClass="reportGrid"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdr" RowStyle-CssClass="row"
    AllowPaging="false" ShowFooter="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="part_nbr" HeaderText="Part #" ItemStyle-Width="200px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="qty_requested" HeaderText="Qty" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:GridView>               

<br /><br /><br />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtpart" runat="server" Width="125px" Visible="true" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind file (.cs) :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("part_nbr");
    dt.Columns.Add("qty_requested");

    var dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["part_nbr"] = "part1";
    dr["qty_requested"] = "1";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    var dr2 = dt.NewRow();
    dr2["part_nbr"] = "part2";
    dr2["qty_requested"] = "1";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr2);

    var dr3 = dt.NewRow();
    dr3["part_nbr"] = "part3";
    dr3["qty_requested"] = "1";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr3);

    gvOrderItems.DataSource = dt;
    gvOrderItems.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= gvOrderItems.ClientID %> input[type="text"]').keydown(function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').children('td, th').css('background-color', '#ff0000');
        });
    });
</script>
```

It will bind the `keydown` function to every TextBox in the GridView and will change the background color of each `TD` and `TH` to red.

You can also set the background color directly to the `TR`, but some older browsers can't handle that (IE).

```
$(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#ff0000');
```